# How can I migrate a DSX Notebook to Spark 2.0?

Tags: data-science-experience

It's currently tied to Spark 1.6, but I want to use SparkSession, among other new features in Spark. How can I do the migration without copying every cell to a new notebooK?

Comment: Could you please tag this as 'dsx' as well?

Comment: Tried to several times. It's not sticking.

Comment: Somebody defined dsx as a synonym for data-science-experience. Yay, we no longer have to tag both :-) http://stackoverflow.com/tags/data-science-experience/info

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for automatic code conversion from spark 1.6 to spark 2.0, i don't think that is available.

You can make changes in the same notebook and just change the kernel to spark 2.0 to run with spark 2.0 spark service.

[image: Check this UI jupyter notebook option]

Or if you don't want to touch your old notebooks,  just duplicate it.
[image: Duplicate Notebook]

As far as manually doing changes, you will need to refer to pyspark or scala programming guide to convert your code.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html

Thanks,
Charles.

Comment: No code changes, just the kernel. Your answer works.